# Get user information by key with value in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

Could someone show me an example how to catch notifications from Firebase Console panel with advanced options where you can post text, value, and key. How could I catch this in the code ?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    }
```

This method is responsible for catching. UserInfo is a dictionary which contains all of the stuffs. I would like to get key's with values from this info.

Thanks in advance!

**ANSWER :**

Whenever you want get smth via your own keys and values it is going to be like this :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        let info = userInfo as NSDictionary
        let name = info.value(forKey: "Name")
        let lastName = info.value(forKey: "LastName")
        let age = info.value(forKey: "Age")

    }
```

Comment: When you use this method, do you see the userInfo dictionary values?

Comment: Yes I see them, but if i do it like this then i recive nil.

Comment: Regarding your answer, you can also use userInfo as [ AnyHashable: Any ] if you want to use swift standard objects